# Spin 1/2 as belt trick in a smooth field

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory, topology, spinors

In the (English) Wikipedia article on [Spinor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor), there is an [animation](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Belt_Trick.ogv), demonstrating the Dirac belt trick as a model for Spin 1/2.

My interpretation of that animation goes like this: If you rotate an *object within space* by 360°, obviously in the end you don't change anything. If, on the other hand, you have a *field*, the situation is a different one. Imagine, you grab a curtain at one point and twist your hand. After a rotation by 360°, the curtain is by no means in its original state, instead you twisted the curtain round your finger. I.e. a rotation of *a signle point of a field* by 360° is by no means the identity. There is a (non homeomorphic-to-$\mathbb{R}^3$) way, though, to smoothly connect a single point to it's vicinity that admits rotation of that point without coiling up the vicinity. This construction exactly yields the 720° symmetry that spin 1/2 particles have.

My questions are:

- Is this a viable explanation for spin or merely suitable as a loose visualization of a 720° symmetry?
- If it is a viable microscopic description of a spin field, how do $SU(2)$ and spinor fields emerge from this microscopic description?

Comment: I cannot answer that question better than by referring to the animation. It shows a cube (representing a single (oriented) point) and belts connected to the cube (representing the smooth, oriented manifold the point belongs to). The point rotates, while at infinity the belts don't move at all. That's what I mean by "rotation of a single point of a field". I'm not sure, whether this is best described by a metric on a smooth manifold or a vector field or what else.

Answer (score 2):

From a mathematical standpoint, the belt trick should really be understood as a path inside *the space of rotations* $SO(3)$. You can continuously parametrize a path of rotations (around some axis) from 0º (the identity transformation) all the way up to 360º (the identity transformation again). The belt trick is a visualization of the fact that this path of rotations cannot be deformed, within $SO(3)$, to a constant path; in terms of the belt trick, it means you cannot wiggle the (once-twisted) belt so that it is untwisted (the twisting throughout the belt represents each stage in your path through rotation space -- the untwisted belt would then represent a constant path). But if you run through that path twice, it turns out that it can be deformed to a constant path -- this is the belt trick.

Now $SU(2)$ is what topologists call the double cover of $SO(3)$, which means it "unwinds" this closed loop (the path from 0º rotation up to to 360º rotation) into a non-closed path. In $SU(2)$ we can then understand that what looked like a closed loop inside $SO(3)$ in some sense "doesn't really land us back where we started". More specifically, there is a morphism $SU(2) \to SO(3)$ such that if we take our closed loop described above, break it up into many little pieces, and then "lift" each piece up to $SU(2)$ (which can be done because that morphism is locally injective), we will end up with a non-closed path inside $SU(2)$ (which in this case will end at $-I$, provided we lifted the $0º$ rotation to $I$).

(NB: when I say "the path from 0º rotation up to 360º rotation", this is an imprecise short version of parametrizing the path within $SO(3)$ that at time $t$ rotates space (around some fixed axis) by $2 \pi t$ radians -- strictly speaking, a 360º rotation *is just the identity transformation*).

Physically, the spin of a spin 1/2 particle corresponds to the defining (also called spinor) representation of $SU(2)$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ (given by multiplication of matrices). Since in this representation $I$ does not act the same as $-I$, it will follow that the path from 0º through 360º, lifted to $SU(2)$, will end in a group element that acts differently from the initial one.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :)
To link your answer to my question I am missing a physical interpretation of what it means to have a field which assigns every point in space a representative of $SO(2)$ or $SU(2)$. This group member ought to to describe something -- some kind of rotation I guess. This rotation could be a twist in space (or a twist in a field in space) similar to what the animation shows and that's what my question is about in the end.

Comment: Pedro, I have wondered about this issue for years and now for the first time I have a perfectly comprehensible answer! what makes it so for me is the fact that you included what sounds like topology in your explanation. Where can I learn more about group theory and topology (for a beginner)?

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Topology and group theory are huge areas of math, so your question is a bit broad. The area of topology that is directly relevant to the belt trick is called covering space theory. It is generally explained in books about algebraic topology. I'd start by looking at Bredon's Topology and Geometry, and/or Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.